# Are extended interfaces getting GC after the main object is deleted?

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection

are extended interfaces in javascript are getting removed by Garbage Collectors when the main interface is deleted / removed?

When I'm setting a interval with console.log to check if the object still exists it is logging even when the main-object is deleted.

Comment: What is an "extended interface"? JS doesn't have interfaces as a language construct.

Comment: What do you mean by "*check if the object still exists*"?

Comment: @Bergi Guessing OP refers to TypeScript or to `Object.create`

Comment: Im refer to typescript.

Comment: @WallahPeter Interfaces only exist in TypeScript, when you transpile TypeScript to JavaScript they get ignored